# How to detect (and style) if two floating DIVs are stacking vertically due to lack of container width?

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing kind of a toolbar in a responsive design. The toolbar sections are implemented as floating DIVs which go side by side with a nice gap between them. However, on lower width devices the DIVs are getting stacked vertically as there is less and less space. That's of course a good thing, but there is one little problem: they are stacking on each other without a vertical gap, or with twice as big vertical gap then it should be (wether I use padding on the container bar or margin on each toolbar section DIV). Neither of this two look too great.

The DIVs can have dynamic width, I don't know exactly on which container width they will get stacked, so I can't use some kind of width breakpoints and media queryies.

How could I style the DIVs taking the possible vertical stacking into account, so that in case of vertical stacking, there would be correct gap between them?

I only need to support modern browsers (newer Chrome, newer Firefox, IE9+).

Comment: can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't target them with a media query (because you are uncertain when they will stack) then you have no choice but to add a top margin (or padding, depending on your needs) to them both. This will keep them in line with each other when they aren't stacked (as they will both have the same top margin/padding) and it will give a vertical space between them when they collapse.

You can even add a negative top margin to the containing element so that your top margin on your floating divs won't have any visible effect until they collapse.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I didn't find this out... Thank you. I just need to add a 0px top padding and some bottom padding to the container and it will work indeed. Similar technic can be done with left and right paddings/margins.